# Need to generate support package

Tags: packages, support

How can I generate automaticalty this package on CD server (Azure) as /sitecore/admin path is denied.
As recommended on this https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/406145

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For CD you can do it manually by following this on the same url https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/406145 -

[image]

[image]